# Displaying records by integer value

Tags: c++

I have to display the records based on the integer value in an array. For instance, if I have an array i.e.

```
2, 3, 5, 3, 6, 8, 10, 1, 9, 7
```

I would need to display 3 and 5 based on the integer 2. Then it should display 6,8 and 10 based on integer 3 and then 9 based on 1. So my display array would be:

```
3,5
6,8,10
9
```

So far, I haven't been able to form any algorithm/code.. How to proceed on this one?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what is supposed to happen with the last `7`?

Comment: "I haven't been able" is not an adequate problem description, sorry. The problem seems fairly straightforward and can be solved with a few loops. What have you got?

Comment: @gspr One way I could try is to get the first element of array in a variable and then a run a loop based on the value of the first element to print the next elements maybe? Oh and that 7 gets discarded as there is no data present beyond that number

Comment: That sounds great. Give it a go.

Comment: @scypx: I suggest you try to code up your suggestion. Best case, you succeed. Worst case, you're much more likely to get help with your broken coden than a question like this :-)   Another question you might wanna ask yourself is what you want to happen if there were some, more than zero but less than seven, entries after that `7`.

Answer (score 0):

tested it with your given array...

```
void display_records(std::vector<int> vi) {
    int tmp = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<vi.size(); i++){

        for(int j=1;j<=vi[i];j++){
            index = i + j;
            tmp = vi[index];
            if((i+j) < vi.size()) {      //to prevent it going out of range
            std::cout << tmp << " " ;
            }
        }
        i = i + vi[i];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this: (i am not sure if i understood your question) (not tested)

```
void displayRecords(int* vect, int size, int val)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            if(vect[i]==val)
                {
                    int tmp = val;
                    int j = i + 1;

                    while(tmp && j != size)
                    {
                        std::cout<<vect[j]<<" ";
                        j++;
                        tmp--;
                    }

                    break;
                }
        }
}
```